# Scraping webpage in Python can't find text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape [this webpage](https://www.playerprofiler.com/nfl/larry-fitzgerald/) using BeautifulSoup in Canopy 1.6.1. What I want to be able to return is the "College Dominator" rating as well as the "Breakout Age" rating. I think that the reason this isn't working is because it's behind Javascript, but I don't know how to find that information from the scraped data. Please help!

Comment: Would you like to provide which version of python you are using? And could you attach with a link to this Canopy-thing (I haven't heard of it before).

Comment: Include all the information related to your question; don't link to external resources. Distill the page down to the minimum amount example required to exhibit the problem, and show what you're trying to accomplish. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 2):

The page you provided is rendered within the browser with JavaScript (Angular). The actual sent HTML doesn't include the information about "College Dominator". Thus you'll have to render it before you can parse it, I'd recommend using a library more suited for parsing client side rendered pages. 
[Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org) is one such option. With that library you could achieve your results like this:

```
r = session.get("https://www.playerprofiler.com/nfl/larry-fitzgerald/")
r.html.render()
college_dominator = r.html.search("College Dominator {percentage}% ({rank}th)")
# {"rank": 96, "percentage": 51.3}
```